# Is it correct? "I haven't drunk or smoked neither a cigarette nor hookah?"

Tags: grammar, sentence

1) Should it be "nor" between drunk and smoked?
2) How about "neither (countable n) nor (uncountable n)"?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Presumably, "drunk" does not apply to "cigarette" or "hookah”, i.e. it's "I have not ((drunk) or (smoked (cigarette or hookah)))". A comma should be used to emphasize this: "I haven't drunk, nor smoked cigarette or hookah". "nor" isn't absolutely necessary, but it helps disambiguate between "I have not (drunk or smoked)" versus "I have (not drunk) or smoked". Between "cigarette" and "hookah", the word "smoked" is clearly being distributed to both, so negating just "smoked" is sufficient, and putting "nor" between "cigarette" and "hookah" is not necessary not make the negation apply to both; that is, the parsing the "I have (not smoked cigarette) or hookah" doesn't make sense, so we don't need to disambiguate between that and the correct parsing.

Comment: *Cigarette* cannot be a mass noun, like *hookah*. You cannot say *"I smoke cigarette,"* the way you can say *"I smoke hookah."* You need to make it plural: *"... nor smoked cigarettes or hookah."*  Alternatively, you could put an article in, like the OP originally did, and say *"... nor smoked a cigarette or hookah."* But *"... nor smoked cigarette or hookah"* makes you sound like you're uneducated and you don't speak English properly. This is not the kind of advice you should be giving people.

Answer (score 0):

First up, hookah is smoked, not drunk. Second, the use of "not" is a double negative to the word neither. This is how it should be written:
"Neither have I smoked a cigarette nor a hookah." - This already gets your point of never having done it across.

Comment: The subject should come before the verb: "I have", not "have I". And "neither" applies to "cigarette" and "hookah", not "smoked". So it should be "I have smoked neither cigarette nor hookah".

Comment: My bad. I actually meant "Never have I smoked a cigarette or hookah."

Answer (score -1):

I think the simplest answer would be:

I have never drank, smoked, nor done hookah.

(The past tense of "drink" is "drank" by the way!)

Comment: but I wanted to say that I had no such an experience in my whole life. So, present perfect should be used here.

Comment: @user309810: This answer uses present perfect. (Even though the alternative past participle *drank* is used rather than *drunk*. But the past participle *done* is used rather than *did*.)

Comment: @user309810 The use of "have never" should indicate that you have never had any of those experiences in your whole life, just like you want!

Comment: Drink is the present - I like to drink coffee. Drank is the simple past - I drank coffee yesterday. Drunk is the past participle, used for the present perfect and past perfect - I have never drunk coffee, I had never drunk coffee.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I do believe "drunk" is only used when describing people who have drank too much in a short period of time and suffer the consequences of doing so.

Comment: BTW do a hookah is more common than smoke a hookah?

Comment: Peter Shor The correct past participle is "drunk", not "drank". jmrpink even implicitly says they are using the past tense, not past participle: "(The past tense of "drink" is "drank" by the way!)". Perhaps from a descriptivist view, "drank" is an "alternative" past participle, but there is an inherently prescriptivist element to this site. People are coming here to learn standard English, not a linguistic survey of nonstandard dialects.

Comment: "I believe "drunk" is only used when describing people who have drank too much in a short period of time" You are wrong, and should not be giving advice based on your erroneous understanding of English. You should look up "present perfect" and "past participle". Saying "I have not drank" instead of "I have not drunk" is similar to "I have not went" instead of "I have not gone".

Comment: Drunk is (1) the past participle of the verb 'to drink' - I have drunk many different varieties of tea. (2) an adjective meaning 'intoxicated by alcohol' - the man consumed a bottle of whisky in one hour and became drunk as a result. This is easily confirmed in any reputable dictionary. [Oxford Dictionaries] (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/drunk)

Comment: "Have drank" is a gross error.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Is the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drink) dictionary disreputable, then? It gives both *drank* and *drunk* as past participles of *drink*. Comparing other alternative past participles I can think of, it doesn't even mention the clearly non-standard [*drug*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drag) (*look what the cat's drug in*) and it has a [long discussion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sneak) of *sneaked* and *snuck*, saying that *snuck* used to be non-standard, but now is acceptable in the U.S.

Comment: In my opinion, the sentence should be expanded somewhat to read more or less as follows:  "I haven't ever drunk an alcoholic drink, nor smoked a cigarette, cigar, pipe, or hookah."  That should cover all the bases, to use an American idiom.   There are other possibilities: "Have never" instead of "haven't ever", or "drunk alcohol" instead of "drunk an alcoholic drink", or "smoked tobacco" instead of "smoked a cigarette, etc."